# Calling Apex class from trigger - issues with passing a list

Tags: trigger, sobject

I am trying to call my Apex class from a trigger:

```
trigger newCrossSellAccounts on Account (before insert) {
   crossSellModule.insertAfterAccount2(trigger.new);
}
```

On the class I have:

```
public void insertAfterAccount2(list<account> accountList){
```

When I try to save trigger I get error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: crossSellModule.insertAfterAccount2(LIST<Account>) at line 2 column 4
```

Now from [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) it says .new "Returns a list of the new versions of the sObject records." I tried to change the function on class to:

```
public void insertAfterAccount2(sObject<account> accountList){
```

But I get error:

```
Invalid type: sObject<account>
```

Should I loop thru and create a list in trigger first? Or is there are workaround. Also, how one would test such trigger/class combination?

Comment: I think you need to declare your function as static: `public static void insertAfterAccount2(list<account> accountList){`

Comment: The reason you are getting the `Invalid type: sObject<account>` error is because you should be using   `List<sObject>` rather than `sObject<account>`

Answer (score 6):

As @Lex mentioned above the reason the code below is not working is because `insertAfterAccount2` is not a static method and can not be called without first instantiating an instance of the `CrossSellModule` class.

```
trigger newCrossSellAccounts on Account (before insert) {
   crossSellModule.insertAfterAccount2(Trigger.new);
}
```

If you make the method static as shown below then it should fix the problem:

```
public static void insertAfterAccount2(List<Account> accountList) {
```

The reason you are getting the `Invalid type: sObject<account>` error is because you should be using   `List<SObject>` rather than `sObject<account>`

**FYI:** The Trigger Context Variables are global and do not need to be passed directly. You could use `Trigger.new` in any class that is called from a trigger.

Comment: Could you please explain more about static methods? Is simply changing to a static method make the code work, as it saved successfully? Regarding the last point - should I then call the class as crossSellModule.insertAfterAccount2();?

Comment: More info on static methods can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_static.htm). Its your decision on wether to pass in the `Trigger.new` list. It may make the class easier to understand, also if you plan on re-using that class somewhere else (e.g. in a Controller) then it makes more sense to pass in the List.